# Can webpack be used to inject javascript into html static templates?

Tags: javascript, templates, webpack, bundler, static-html

I would like to bundle several javascript files with webpack. In the course of doing so, I would like to take some values that are present in my javascript files (prior to bundling but in the course of processing) and to inject them into some static html files in the same directory as my bundle files.

Is this something webpack can do and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a plugin, does this do what you want? https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin

Comment: I was looking at this but the lack of examples wasn't helpful. The documentation is terribly written. The events example seems like the best use case but I can't figure it out.